# MongoDB: Get counts of documents in referred schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have 3 collections `category`, `subcategory` and `products`

**References**

1. `category_id` is referred in `subcategory`
2. `subcategory_id` is referred in `products`

**How can I get**

1. Number of `products` in each `category` ?
2. Number of `subcategories` in each `category`?
3. Number of `products` in each `subcategory`?

#### - When I query for categories I should get `category name` and `count of products` in it.

```
[
 {
   name: "catName 1",
   products: 2
 },
{
   name: "catName 1",
   products: 0
 }
]
```

#### - When I query for subcategories I should get `subcategories name` and `count of products` in it.

```
[
 {
   name: "subCatName 1",
   products: 2
 },
{
   name: "subCatName 1",
   products: 0
 },
{
   name: "subCatName 3",
   products: 0
 }
]
```

**Example Schema:**

```js
// category
[
 {
   _id: "5f886eb2d41da75dd5a90bfc"
   catName: "catName 1"
 },
{
   _id: "5f886eb2d41da75dd5a90bfd"
   catName: "catName 2"
 }
]
```

```js
// subcategory
[
 {
   _id: "6f886eb2d41da75dd5a90bfc"
   subCatName: "subCatName 1",
   category: "5f886eb2d41da75dd5a90bfc" // cat 1
 },
{
   _id: "6f886eb2d41da75dd5a90bfd"
   subCatName: "subCatName 2",
   category: "5f886eb2d41da75dd5a90bfc" // cat 1
 },
{
   _id: "6f886eb2d41da75dd5a90bfa"
   subCatName: "subCatName 2",
   category: "5f886eb2d41da75dd5a90bfd" // cat 2
 }
]
```

```js
// product 

[
 {
   _id: "1f886eb2d41da75dd5a90bfd"
   productName: "productName 1",
   subcategory: "6f886eb2d41da75dd5a90bfc" // subcategory 1
 },
{
   _id: "2f886eb2d41da75dd5a90bfd"
   productName: "productName 2",
   subcategory: "6f886eb2d41da75dd5a90bfc" // subcategory 1
 }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### *When I query for categories I should get category name and count of products in it.*

- `$lookup` join with subcategory collection, pass category id in let,
- `$match` category id condition
- `$lookup` join with product collection
- `$project` get total products count using `$size`
- `$project` to show required fields, `$reduce` to get total products count from each subcategory

```
db.category.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "subcategory",
      let: { category: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$category", "$category"] } } },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "product",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "subcategory",
            as: "products"
          }
        },
        { $project: { products: { $size: "$products" } } }
      ],
      as: "products"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: "$catName",
      products: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$products",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: { $add: ["$$value", "$$this.products"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BdeupSun06_)

---

#### *When I query for subcategories I should get subcategories name and count of products in it*.

- `$lookup` join with product collection
- `$project` to show required fields, get total products count using `$size`

```
db.subcategory.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "product",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "subcategory",
      as: "products"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: "$subCatName",
      products: { $size: "$products" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RDhFr1Nd8bl)